# original SASS, responsive function syntax

Tags: sass

Original sass syntax having just been replaced by what is an scss syntax, it is quite hard to get a hand on docs

[Reading this post](https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-responsive-breakpoints-sass/) for responsive functions, I'd be looking to know how to write the following in original sass syntax :

```
$breakpoints: (
  'small'  : ( min-width:  767px ),
  'medium' : ( min-width:  992px ),
  'large'  : ( min-width: 1200px )
);
@mixin respond-to($name) {
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $name) {
    @media #{inspect(map-get($breakpoints, $name))} {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @else {
    @warn "Unfortunately, no value could be retrieved from `#{$breakpoint}`. "
        + "Please make sure it is defined in `$breakpoints` map.";
  }
}
```

Can it just be done, or using the less/scss syntax is required ?

Comment: Not sure why you've added the Less tag because this question seems to be about SCSS to Sass conversion.

Comment: Scss is close to less. Original sass is different. Don't get when it is named sass when your file is .scss, when you could have a raw .sass one

Comment: No, SCSS and Less have only the concepts in common. The way the features are implemented/called/used is very different. It a bit like adding lemons tag to an oranges question because both have Vitamin C :D

Comment: I understand what you mean. Thing is, sass is strict, scss and less are (can be) loose, syntaxically speaking. The "sass is scss" is then quite confusing. But there might be reasons, i'm off topic i guess. I was ultimately trying to get a hand on some OG sass doc/reference; google won't provide it. Maybe you know

Comment: Yup, SCSS and Less are closer to CSS syntax whereas Sass uses the indented syntax (I think Ruby or Python or both use a similar syntax). But yeah, this discussion would be off topic, so I'd leave it there :)

Comment: Sounds like this potential rant happened two or three years ago aha. Wasnt around. Let's leave it there you're right! Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

still no docs for genuine sass, but using sass-convert can be an answer

```
sass-convert file.scss file.sass
```

the following outputs in genuine sass :

```
$breakpoints: ("small": (min-width: 767px), "medium": (min-width: 992px), "large": (min-width: 1200px))
=respond-to($name)
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $name)
    @media #{inspect(map-get($breakpoints, $name))}
      @content
  @else
    @warn "Unfortunately, no value could be retrieved from `#{$breakpoint}`. " + "Please make sure it is defined in `$breakpoints` map."
```